# Complex Rails query across multiple tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table of `Postcodes` which is joined to a table of `Companies`.
There is a join table `CompaniesPostcode`.

I want to take the `postcode` someone enters, search the join table for matches, and return the `company_ids`.

*Then*, I want to pass this query into another table (called `company_selected_categories`) to find what categories the company has selected, and create a count of each `category_id`.

I then want to render from each `category_id` the `name`, `image` and count of how many `partners` - and only render if this count is > 0.

More info on my data modelling can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/pressdapp/e96bd76cbf70b4e100c03bc728d3c5ff).

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: I'd suggest adding the relevant models to this question - it's a little unclear, for example, whether `company_selected_categories` are associated with anything else (they likely should be), or if they're completely stand alone. It's near impossible to create an accurate answer without fleshing this out further. Let me know when you've done this - happy to take another look :)

Comment: @SRack thanks - I've made  gist here: https://gist.github.com/pressdapp/e96bd76cbf70b4e100c03bc728d3c5ff

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `company selected categories` is a join table? Without models as SRack said it's hard to give an answer, but it might look something like this:

```
Postcodes.joins(company: :categories)
         .where("postcode.code = ?", user_input)
         .group("categories.id")
         .select("categories.id, categories.name, categories.image, count(companies.id)")
```